# COBOL - Understanding SET MYSELF

Tags: cobol, gnucobol, cobol85

In my COBOL program I have the following statement:

```
SET MYSELF (STATUS) TO -1.
```

What this statement does? I don't understand the MYSELF and STATUS words. It seems that the it gives the status parameter the value -1, am I right? What MYSELF means?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MYSELF is a reserved word that enables a compiler-supplied task item to refer to the attributes of its own process. So you are setting STATUS in your own process to -1.

[COBOL ANSI-74 Programming Reference Manual](https://public.support.unisys.com/aseries/docs/ClearPath-MCP-18.0/86000296-210.pdf) (PDF Link)

> The reserved word MYSELF is a compiler-supplied task item that
>   enables a program to access its own task attributes. Thus, any
>   attribute of a given task can be referenced within that task as
>   ATTRIBUTE attribute-name OF MYSELF.
>
> For example, CHANGE ATTRIBUTE DECLAREDPRIORITY OF MYSELF TO 90.
>   CHANGE ATTRIBUTE DECLAREDPRIORITY OF ATTRIBUTE PARTNER OF MYSELF TO 65.
>
> The second example illustrates another task running with a task that you are running. 
>   The PARTNER attribute refers to the other task and the example changes the
>   DECLAREDPRIORITY of the other task.

Comment: Thank you for the additional background. One thing to know is that this is *not COBOL* but an Unisys extension, as noted aboce.

Comment: Just a note: this is not a "common" extension to COBOL74, for example the "VAX-11 COBOL-74 Language Reference Manual" does not reference anything like this.

Answer (score 1):

In a "plain" COBOL program this statement would not be valid. `MYSELF` would be an entry below an `OCCURS` (a "table cell") and `STATUS` would be the index to use (= a numeric variable).

But as the `SET` statement can only ("standard COBOL") adjust variables of type `POINTER` or `INDEX` and both cannot be set to be negative this statement would normally be invalid.

There are some implementations where you can use `SET` to adjust any numeric variable (where the -1 would be valid if the target is a signed variable), but as @JerryTheGreek pointed out it looks to be **NO COBOL** but the "Task-Attribute Identifiers (Extension to ANSI X3.23-1974 COBOL)".